# Putting punctuation to the right position in a text (in Tcl)

Tags: tcl

I have a text which has slightly been modified by a tcl code. Now it looks as follows:

```
word1 word2 word3 word4 , word5 word6 word7 word8 . word9 , word10 word11 word12 ; word13 word14 word15...
```

As you can see, characters like . or , are removed from the words. I would like to put them into their original position, that is

```
word1 word2 word3 word4, word5 word6 word7 word8. word9, word10 ...
```

As I work with tcl 8.0, I would like to use the regsub-command if possible. (*string replace* is not implemented in tcl 8.0)

Any help is welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tcl 8.0 is 25 years old! See https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Changes+in+Tcl%2FTk .  Why on earth are you using such a prehistoric version?

Comment: I have to use it because my colleagues work with it. For some reason they decided not to update tcl and stick to version 8.0. If I write a code in tcl 8.6 then it will probably not run in tcl 8.0.

Comment: If you can persuade them to update to Tcl8.6, their Tcl8.0 code will almost certainly run just fine.  The Tcl maintainers are very careful about backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
regsub -all {[[:space:]]+([[:punct:]])} $text {\1} new_text
```

---

Thanks for your comments folks

```
regsub -all -nocase {[ \t]+([^a-z0-9])} $text {\1} new_text
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Your code doesn't seem to have any effect on the text. It remains unchanged. If I display $new_text then it is identical to $text (in tcl 8.0).

Comment: I think the switch command -all does not exist under tcl 8.0. At least in combination with regexp it cannot be used.

Comment: The -all option was recognized in 8.0. But character classes (like [[:punct:]]) weren't.

Comment: You have to write the regular expression using Henry Spencer's basic syntax: `regsub -all {[ ]+([,.])} $text {\1} new_text`. As @SchelteBron commented correctly, there were no predefined character classes/ ranges, but also `\s` was missing.

Comment: ... I can only support the others: Get your colleagues to step up to using Tcl 8.6.